# using SQLite with mod_perl

Tags: sqlite, mod-perl

I have been successfully using SQLite as a data store for my web applications, but now I am implementing a web site with mod_perl, and am running into database locking issues.

As expected, my entire web application is loaded by the Plack Apache handler (Plack::Handler::Apache2) when the web server is started. Well, the first db query creates a lock on the entire database, and any subsequent query that has to modify the db fails.

What is my way out? Can I use SQLite in a persistent web environment or not? Should I be looking for some other db store?

I am not a fan of MySQL, and don't want to use it. I could potentially use PostGres, but I'd rather use something lightweight, and preferably sql-based as using key/value databases such as Tokyo Cabinet would require learning a whole new way. I'd rather really use SQLite.

Answer (score 0):

If you have an open handle to the database, it can cause this issue.  I have had problems when iterating over a result set during a log process causes the lock to stick around.

Try and fetch all the rows for the query and call `$sth->finish()` to clear up the lock.  You will use a little more memory, but you will avoid the locking.

Knowing you are going to do this, you can make use of `$sth->fetchall_arrayref()` or `$sth->fetchall_hashref()`

Answer (score 0):

Use Tokyo Cabinet's table database.